# Function in each cell column can automatically write words PASS and FAIL

Tags: c#

I need your help and advice,

I am using Gridview in C# Windows Application and need your advice to solve my issues bellow :

How i can make function in each cell column B which can automatically write words PASS and FAIL with the following Roles:

- First cell in column B : It will automatically write "PASS"
- Second cell in column B : If value in second cell column A less than Value in First cell column A then in second cell column B will Automatically "FAIL" otherwise will "PASS"
- Third cell in column B : If value in third cell column A less than value in First cell column A then in third cell column B will Automatically "FAIL" otherwise will "PASS"

Note : I am not using Database connection for GridView data, i am using GridView to load data from fingerprint Device

Here is picture sample

[image]

Really appreciate and thanks in advance for help

Comment: Can you share the code which populates the data in the GridView? Logically you should have the data source populated with the proper values before you bind it to the GridView.

Comment: Hello Chetan Ranpariya,

https://www.mediafire.com/file/285bztvg1vfhczg/BioMatrix.zip

I uploaded here, Appreciate for your help

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do it this way.

The GridView is straight forward, I may say. Nothing's so special here :

```
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true">

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=ColumnA}" 
                  Header="ColumnA" Width="100"/>

            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding=
                      "{Binding Path=ColumnB}" 
                  Header="ColumnB" Width="100"/>

        </GridView>
```

And then create a generic class like this to store the data :

```
public class AnyClass
{
    //This value is the one to be compared with ColumnA
    public int? ValueToCompare { get; set; }

    public int ColumnA { get; set; }

    //ColumnB will throw a result based on two columns above
    public string ColumnB { get { return ValueToCompare.HasValue && ValueToCompare.Value <= ColumnA ? "PASS" : "FAILED"; } }
}
```

And load the data the way it's shown here :

```
public class AnyDataSource
{
    //public List<AnyClass> List { get; set; }

    public List<AnyClass> LoadData()
    {
        //Load data from data source
        List<AnyClass> list = new List<AnyClass>();
        list.Add(new AnyClass { ColumnA = 3 });
        list.Add(new AnyClass { ColumnA = 1 });
        list.Add(new AnyClass { ColumnA = 6 });

        //Get the first value
        int valueToCompare = list[0].ColumnA;

        //Set the ValueToCompare property of every row with this first value
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            item.ValueToCompare = valueToCompare;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

And use it to set the ItemsSource of the GridView programmatically :

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var data = new AnyDataSource();

        YourListView.ItemsSource = data.LoadData();
    }
```

That's it.

I know someone may come up with a better solution, but for now you can use this approach for awhile.

Comment: Thanks Pak Erlangga, Appreciate for your help,

I will try,

Comment: No problem. :) If it works, just submit my answer as the best answer, please.